# How to get per class precision, recall and f1 score for multiclass classification for each of the fold of cross validation in sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset on which I wish to perform multiclass classification using `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()`. After fitting the model, I want to get the precission, recall and f1 score for each of the classes for each fold of cross validation.

- According to the docs, there exists [sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html), in which I can provide `average=None` as a parameter to get the precision, recall, fscore per class.
- There exists [sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), in which I can provide a custom function in the `scoring` parameter. However, the function has to return a number. In my case, I wish to return a list, which is not possible.
- There also exists [sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html), in which I can give multiple functions as list to the `scoring` parameter. This would require me to create `3*NUMBER_OF_CLASSES` different functions and pass these to the `scoring` parameter.

Is there a simpler method available?

Comment: Do you want to just print the results? If yes, use a single function, print all the values in that, and that return any single value.

Comment: Yup, that is one workaround, that is print the result in the function that I feed to `scoring` parameter of `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`. But I wish to know, if there is an **official/proper** way provided by sklearn.

Comment: I dont think so. `cross_val_score` or `cross_validate` just iterate over all the folds from `cv` and record the scores. You can always iterate the loops yourself.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201464/cross-validation-metrics-in-scikit-learn-for-each-data-split/54202609#54202609 for some adaptable ideas.