# Should Cross Validation Score be performed on original or split data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When I want to evaluate my model with cross validation, should I perform cross validation on original (data thats not split on train and test) or on train / test data?

I know that training data is used for fitting the model, and testing for evaluating. If I use cross validation, should I still split the data into train and test, or not?

```
features = df.iloc[:,4:-1]
results = df.iloc[:,-1]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

clf = LogisticRegression()
model = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

accuracy_test = cross_val_score(clf, x_test, y_test, cv = 5)
```

Or should I do like this:

```
features = df.iloc[:,4:-1]
results = df.iloc[:,-1]

clf = LogisticRegression()
model = clf.fit(features, results)

accuracy_test = cross_val_score(clf, features, results, cv = 5)), 2)
```

Or maybe something different?

Comment: The `test` part shouldn't be used for anything except the final evaluation. BTW, you have a mistake in your code (in the first block). You're fitting `clf` using the training data and then you're applying cross validation using the test data.

Comment: Well thats my question?
Which block of code is more accurate?

I know that training data is used for fitting the model, and testing for evaluating.

If I use cross validation, should I still split the data into train and test, or not?

Comment: I have read this but there is no answer to my question

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Anyway, to evaluate your model there two general ways, cross-validation and test part. you can use any of them. In the first bloack you're mixing both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your approaches are wrong.

- In the first one, you apply cross validation to the *test* set, which is meaningless
- In the second one, you first fit the model with your whole data, and then you perform cross validation, which is again meaningless. Moreover, the approach is redundant (your fitted `clf` is not used by the `cross_val_score` method, which does its own fitting)

Since you are not doing any hyperparameter tuning (i.e. you seem to be interested only in performance assessment), there are two ways:

- **Either** with a separate test set
- **Or** with cross validation

First way (test set):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

clf = LogisticRegression()
model = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)

accuracy_test = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Second way (cross validation):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

clf = LogisticRegression()

# shuffle data first:
features_s, results_s = shuffle(features, results)
accuracy_cv = cross_val_score(clf, features_s, results_s, cv = 5, scoring='accuracy')

# fit the model afterwards with the whole data, if satisfied with the performance:
model = clf.fit(features, results)
```

Comment: So for example, if i want to test multiple classifiers, I can add them in for loop, and then check the accuracy_cv of each one of them ( with "Second Way" that you posted), and then, i fit the data with the model that gave the best accuracy_cv?

Comment: @taga that's correct, and you could do this with either ways (test set or CV). Slight caveat if using CV is, `cross_val_score` by itself does not guarantee that each one of your classifiers will be fit & evaluated in the *same* data subsets; if you want to be sure on this, you should better use `KFold` instead. You can easily adapt the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201464/cross-validation-metrics-in-scikit-learn-for-each-data-split/54202609#54202609) (although it's a bit overkill, and you could just stick with what shown above).

Comment: And should I do coss validation with training or testing. Im looking at your "Second Way", should i put train or test in your accuracy_cv?

Comment: @taga please read closer; there is an either/or statement before, and there is no test set whatsoever in the 2nd approach. Whenever a test set exists, it is used only for *test* (no train, no CV, not anything else)

Answer (score 2):

I will try to summarize the "best practice" here:

1) If you want to train your model, fine-tune parameters, and do final evaluation, I recommend you to split your data into `training`|`val`|`test`.

You fit your model using the `training` part, and then you check different parameter combinations on the `val` part. Finally, when you're sure which classifier/parameter obtains the best result on the `val` part, you evaluate on the `test` to get the final rest.

Once you evaluate on the `test` part, you shouldn't change the parameters any more.

2) On the other hand, some people follow another way, they split their data into `training` and `test`, and they finetune their model using cross-validation on the training part and at the end they evaluate it on the `test` part.

If your data is quite large, I **recommend** you to use the first way, but if your data is small, the 2.

Comment: Can you give me the example code of splitting data into training|val|test?

Comment: use the same function `train_test_split` twice on the `training` part.