# What is the difference between getting score value from kfold,fit,score vs using cross_val_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

It seems basic, but I can't see the difference and the advantages or disadvantages between the following 2 ways:

first way:

```
    kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

second way:

```
cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=2)
```

It seems that the 2 ways do the same thing, and the second one is shorter (one line).

What am I missing ?

What are the differences and advantages or disadvantages for each way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably, the best way to see such differences is to experiment, although here the situation is rather easy to discern:

`clf.score` is in a loop; hence, after the loop execution, it contains just the score in the last validation fold, forgetting everything that has been done before in the previous `k-1` folds.

`cross_cal_score`, on the other hand, returns the score from all `k` folds. It is generally preferable, but it lacks a `shuffle` option (which shuffling is always advisable), so you need to manually shuffle the data first, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201464/cross-validation-metrics-in-scikit-learn-for-each-data-split/54202609#54202609), or use it with `cv=KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True)`.

A disadvantage of the `for` loop + `kfold` method is that it is run serially, while the CV procedure in `cross_val_score` can be parallelized in multiple cores with the `n_jobs` argument.

A limitation of `cross_val_score` is that it cannot be used with multiple metrics, but even in this case you can use [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html), as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934157/why-roc-auc-produces-weird-results-in-sklearn) - not necessary to use `for + kfold`.

The use of `kfold` in a `for` loop gives additional flexibility for cases where neither `cross_val_score` nor `cross_validate` may be adequate, for example using the scikit-learn wrapper for Keras while still getting all the metrics returned by native Keras during training, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867078/how-to-get-training-validation-loss-of-keras-models-in-cross-validation/60868006#60868006); or if you want to permanently store the different folds in separate variables/files, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903295/how-do-i-access-the-datasets-after-running-k-fold-with-scikit-learn/60904209#60904209).

In short:

- if you just want the scores for a single metric, stick to `cross_val_score` (shuffle first and parallelize).
- if you want multiple metrics, use `cross_validate` (again, shuffle first and parallelize).
- if you need a greater degree of control or monitor of the whole CV process, revert to using `kfold` in a `for` loop accordingly.

Comment: `cross_val_score` Returns
scores - array of float, shape=(len(list(cv)),)
Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation. NOT the average score.

Comment: @oldwooki ooops,,, you are right of course, my bad (although I have it correctly in the linked answer)! Fixed now, thanks for pointing out.