# cross_val_score behaves differently with different classifiers in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation, nearest-neighbor

I'm having some difficulty with `cross_val_score()` in `sklearn`.

I have instantiated a `KNeighborsClassifier` with the following code:

```
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=28)
```

I am then using cross validation to understand the accuracy of this classifier on my `df` of features (`x`) and target series (`y`) with the following:

```
cv_score_av = np.mean(cross_val_score(clf, x, y, cv=5))
```

Each time I run the script I was hoping to achieve a different result, however there is not an option to set `random_state=None` like there is with `RandomForestClassifier()` for example. Is there a way to achieve a different result with each run or am I going to have to manually shuffle my data randomly prior to running `cross_val_score` on my `KNeighborsClassifier` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some misunderstanding here from your part; the `random_state` argument in the Random Forest refers to the algorithm itself, and not to the cross validation part. Such an argument is necessary here, since RF includes indeed some randomness in model building (a *lot* of it, in fact, as already implied by the very name of the alforithm); but knn, in contrast, is a deterministic algorithm, so in principle there is no need for it to use any `random_state`.

That said, your question is indeed valid; I have [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201464/cross-validation-metrics-in-scikit-learn-for-each-data-split/54202609#54202609) in the past on this annoying and inconvenient absence of a shuffling argument in `cross_val_score`. Digging into the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), we see that under the hood, the function uses either `StratifiedKFold` or `KFold` to build the folds:

> **cv : *int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional***
>
> For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and `y` is either binary or multiclass, [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) is used. In all other cases, [`KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) is used.

and both of these functions, as you can easily see from the linked documentation pages, use `shuffle=False` as default value.

Anyway, the solution is simple, consisting of a single additional line of code; you just need to replace `cv=5` with a call to a previously defined `StratifiedKFold` object with `shuffle=True`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
cv_score_av = np.mean(cross_val_score(ml_10_knn, x, y, cv=skf))
```